# Check If Non Exiting File Is Excutable -Win32 C

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to check if file that i want to create is executable.

The check will be by given file path, for example:

c:\good.txt

I want to check if file is executable before I will create it.

I think to use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  function:

with the `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES`  flag, but I can't use this flag with the `SHGFI_EXETYPE` flag.

It means that I can't use the `SHGFI_EXETYPE` flag on a non exiting file.

Is there any another way to check if file is executable before I create the file?

Comment: `I am trying to check if file that i want to create is executable.
` - since the file does not exist yet, how would you want to retrieve its meta data?

Comment: The check will be by given file path, for example:

c:\good.txt

Comment: if you `copy` `notepad.exe` as `c:\good.txt` you will discover that launching `good.txt' at the command line will indeed start notepad. Without an actual "on disk" file, it's hard to say if a "name" is an executable, but you may be able to do wild guesses looking at the extension. Those wild guesses will fail with the example I just gave you, thought.

Answer (score 3):

A file that does not exist cannot be ether executable or non-executable. The executability of a file (or otherwise) is stored within its metadata, be that a filename, permission bits, attributes or whatever. A file that does not exist has none of those, and hence you cannot check for its executability.

You'll notice that the `SHGetFileInfo` function to which you refer is document thus:

> Retrieves information about an object in the file system, such as a file, folder, directory, or drive root.

Note the bit about it retrieving information about *an object in the file system* (not 'an object not in the file system).

Answer (score 2):

A file which doesn't exist is not executable. You're asking a question which doesn't make sense. 'How hot is the water in this empty glass?' - how can something which doesn't exist have a property?